# Drawing complex shapes in c++ with nested loops

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, nested-loops, shapes

I currently have an assignment which i need to draw some complex shapes in c++ using nested loops. I managed to draw one of them but the other two is still not complete and I don't have an idea on how to draw them.

[These are the shapes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EXCt.png)

[This is my working code for the second shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uasWz.png)

But I can't think of a solution for the first and the third one. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: Explain to yourself, line by line of the figure what the conditions are for drawing stars.
E.g. if the line is odd only draw on the left and right except for the first odd line. And work things out from there.

Comment: Is there any chance you can give an example? I am pretty new to coding so it is kinda hard to understand what is going on and how to solve given problems.